# indesign cc2019 package problem

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, cc-2019

When i make a package indesign does NOT copy all links to the new folder. When i then used to save the document to the new folder the links were updated to the new links folder. Not anymore. When i chose the option relink all to new folder it cant find the links allthough they are there. (except for the links indesign didnt copy, because they are not in the desired folder). This is a pain because i delete old folders and after a week i find out indesign is missing files. I never had this before. Any ideas?. Trashing prefs is a bit of a pain because i have several extensions from other parties, which require a lot of work to reinstall. File names are okay, no strange characters or locked layers. When i manually relink one image it does find the existing ones. I am puzzeled. Appreciate an answer

Answer (score 2):

[image]Is it as simple as checking the "Copy Linked Graphics" checkbox during the packaging process? Also keep in mind that images that appear only on the pasteboard will not be included in the package.